# Create global variable and generate random number and update the variable when the function is called in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

I am kinda new in this coding environment and trying to challange myself with exercises.

I am trying to create global variable called quoteNumber and generate a random number and update this variable every time when the function is called.

However with the code below, every time I call the function quoteNumber variable stays the same and not updated with new random number.

I can solve this putting all variables inside the function but since I am using those variables in different functions I guess it is better for me to create global variable for it.

What are your suggestions?

```js
var quotes = [{"quote":"Knowledge speaks, but wisdom listens.","author":"Jimi Hendrix"}];

var quoteNumber = 0 ;
var generatedQuote = quotes[quoteNumber].quote;
var generatedAuthor = quotes[quoteNumber].author;

function quoteGenerator () {
  quoteNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 1;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = generatedQuote;
  document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = generatedAuthor;
}

function share() {
  document.getElementById("tweet-quote").attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&text=' + encodeURIComponent('"' + generatedQuote + '" ' + generatedAuthor));
}
```

PS- I have shortened the quotes variation and put here not to create confusion

Comment: What triggers `quoteGenerator()`? How are you verifying that it stays the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling the function you are properly updating the `quoteNumber`-variable. However, both `generatedQuote` and `generatedAuthor` are still the value you set from the beginning.
So, after setting the quoteNumber to a new value, you will have to do

```
generatedQuote = quotes[quoteNumber].quote;
generatedAuthor = quotes[quoteNumber].author;
```

To update those variables as well.

Comment: Yes you are right. As you said that I also updated generatedQuote and generatedAuthor variable by putting them again in the function. Now it works :) Thanks

Comment: Just make sure you don't include the `var`-keyword inside the function. If you do, you will have declared local variables that update only inside the function.